# Transformar uma string numérica em uma lista de números em python

Tags: python

Eu preciso transformar uma entrada em uma lista.

A entrada possui a seguinte forma:

```
['[11, 14]', '[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]']
```

é lida de um arquivo `csv`. Observem que é composta por duas `strings`, a primeira `'[11, 14]'`; e a segunda `'[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]'`.

A saída que preciso é uma lista de inteiros:

```
[11, 14, 8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]
```

Procurei aqui no fórum e no google, mesmo encontrado algumas dicas parecidas, não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode trabalhar com JSON, visto que os valores que possuem são sequências no JSON também.

```
>>> json.loads('[1, 2, 3]')  # [1, 2, 3]
```

E, para juntar as listas, você pode utilizar a função [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> itertools.chain([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Assim, ficando:

```
import json
import itertools

linha = ['[11, 14]', '[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]']
resultado = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(json.loads(item) for item in linha))

print(resultado)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PoliteDarkmagentaComputergraphics)</sup>

Comment: Muito boa a resposta. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
entrada = ['[11, 14]', '[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]']

saida = []
for string in entrada:
    #tiro o '[' e o ']' e depois separo pelas virgulas. Isso me retorna uma lista com strings
    lista_strings = string.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')
    #Transformo as strings da lista em inteiros
    lista_inteiros = [int(i) for i in lista_strings]
    saida.append(lista_inteiros)

>>> print(saida)
[[11, 14], [8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['[11, 14]', '[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 82, 84, 93, 97]']
```

Usando listas em compreensão podemos:

```
b=[eval(x) for x in a]   ## [[11, 14], [8, 17, 18, 2...]]
```

Para obter a lista única temos várias hipóteses:

```
c=sum(b,[])
```

ou

```
c=[y for x in a for y in eval(x)]
```

(`eval(...)` pode levantar problemas de segurança se por exemplo
 `a` estiver a ser lido interativamente. Para entradas não controladas convem usar `ast.literal_eval()` em vez de `eval`)

Comment: Prefira usar [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) ao invés de `eval` nestas situações.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss,  Obrigado. Desconheço o literal_eval: Qual é a diferença entre as duas?

Comment: É auto explicativo, [nos docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) tem mais informação. Mas em resumo o `eval` interpreta qualquer comando python enquanto o `ast.literal_eval` apenas valores literais, como strings, inteiros, tuplas, listas, etc.. Dessa maneira se garante que não será executado comando algum a partir da string avaliada.

Comment: Poderemos discutir isso em [eval vs ast.literal_eval: quais as diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326937/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado. Boa ideia!

Answer (score 0):

Bem, ao usar o canal não fiquei apenas aguardando ajuda, estive buscando desde o momento da postagem e consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
import re

lista = ['[11, 14]', '[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]']

listalimpa = []

for dado in lista:
    #Divido as string '[11, 14]' e '[8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]' faço uma divisão 
    for x in dado.split(','):
    #aqui substituo os caracteres indesejados por nada usando o método sub, do módulo re
        listalimpa.append(int(re.sub('\[|\]|,|''\s*', "", x)))
print(listalimpa)
```

A saída ficou como esperado:

```
[11, 14, 8, 17, 18, 24, 29, 37, 44, 49, 51, 55, 62, 63, 64, 76, 82, 84, 93, 97]
```

Bem, e como havia comentado no post original, a resposta não era das mais difíceis.