# eval vs ast.literal_eval: quais as diferenças?

Tags: python

Em Python é comum lermos que [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) é uma alternativa ao [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

- As funções são equivalentes? Tudo o que uma faz a outra também faz?
- Em questões de segurança, há prioridade em utilizar uma ou outra?
- Quais as reais diferenças entre as duas funções?

Comment: No SOen: [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/1452488)

Comment: E. obviamente, vale sempre citar: [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/5878)

Comment: Anderson: Por favor corrige a minha resposta. Eval é mocinho ou bandido? -- Eval é mais Rambo.

Comment: @JJoao não entendi seu comentário

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As duas funções compilam o código, porém `ast.literal_eval` só executa o código se ele for uma literal de um objeto básico: strings, bytes, números, `True`, `False` e `None`.

Além disso são aceitos também tuplas, listas, dicionários e conjuntos desde que contenham apenas os objetos citados acima.

Já o `eval` permite que a string contenha qualquer expressão, portanto, permite executar qualquer tipo de código, pois em python qualquer código pode ser reescrito em forma de expressão.

Na questão de segurança fica óbvio que o `literal_eval` é mais seguro, pois com o `eval` pode-se fazer qualquer coisa que o processo rodando o python tenha permissão para fazer.

Mesmo assim, nem o `literal_eval` pode ser recomendado para interpretar strings fornecidas pelo usuário, pois um usuário malicioso pode criar uma string suficientemente complexa que até mesmo o `literal_eval` pode causar um *crash* no interpretador python no momento da compilação.

A alternativa viável é usar um formato parseável, como `xml` ou `json` que possuem parsers mais seguros.

Answer (score 0):

Isto não é bem uma resposta mas uma opinião (politicamente incorreta).

## Formatos de intercâmbio

Tanto módulos de json, yaml, xml, ... contêm funções que reconhecem os
respectivos formatos (linguagens) e criam uma representação semântica

`parser : STR -> objectoPythonEspecífico`

e serializam `prittyprint : objectoPythonEspecífico -> STR`
ssendo tipicamente usados para intercâmbio de **constantes** estruturadas entre diferentes
contextos (diferentes sessões, processos, linguagens, máquinas, plataformas).

## ast.literal_eval

O `ast.literal_eval` é algo semelhante em que o formato é
um subconjunto pequeno da linguagem Python incluindo

- constantes (str, numeros, tuplos, listas, dicionários)
- podendo usar um conjunto de operadores "pacíficos".

Não permite por exemplo expressões contendo:
(1) variáveis e funções,
(2) indexação de tuplos, listas, dicionários.

O `ast.literal_eval` é não reflexivo.

## eval

O `eval(expressão)`, `exec(strcodigo)`, são bastante mais poderosos:
permite toda a sintaxe
das expressões Python, permitem
reflexividade: podemos ter acesso e definir novas variáveis, funções, etc.

**(in)Segurança**

Felizmente consegue-se fazer coisas perigosas com `eval`, com o Python,
com `system()`, com a `bash`, com qualquer ferramenta poderosa.
Naturalmente tambem se conseguem fazer milagres.

O `eval(str)` tem que ser usado com cuidado quando a `str` tem origens
não controladas e potencialmente adversas. Se a `str` está de algum modo
dependente de interação com o utilizador, a situação é tão perigosa quanto
o utilizador for perigoso.

`eval(rawinput())` é precisamente o que estamos a executar quando corremos
o interpretador Python -- e isso nunca tirou o sono a ninguém. Se fizermos
algo análogo com uma aplicação web: ... vai correr mal!

Não vejo mal nenhum em usar o eval indiscriminadamente nas minhas actividades.
Defini uma calculadora que, à semelhança do interpretador Python, usa algo

```
print(pp(eval(retoca(rawinput("?"))))
```

e que me permite coisas fantásticas e tambem formatar o disco e tudo o mais!

Comment: Sim, o famoso REPL (Read Eval Print Loop)