# Como calcular o resultado de uma expressão aritmética contida em uma tupla respeitando a precedência dos operadores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operadores

Tenho uma tupla contendo os *tokens* de uma expressão aritmética: `('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')`.

Tentei calcular o resultado da expressão, mas não está respeitando a precedência dos operadores. No caso, não está fazendo a multiplicação primeiro:

```
valores = ('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')
soma = 0
for indice, valor in enumerate(valores):
    if str(valor).isalnum():
        if indice == 0:
            soma = int(valor)
        else:
            soma = soma
    elif str(valor) == '+':
        soma += int(valores[indice + 1])
    elif str(valor) == '-':
        soma -= int(valores[indice + 1])
    elif str(valor) == '*':
        soma *= int(valores[indice + 1])

print(soma)
```

Comment: Poderia ser uma string "5 + 2 * 5" também

Comment: Você quer só avaliar essa string específica, ou quer fazer um analisador de expressões completo?

Comment: completo e com (n) número de algarismos

Comment: Tem no mínimo dois problemas na pergunta. O título não tem nada a ver com o problema de operador, e a resposta aceita indica se tratar de um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70). Nas próximas é importante reduzir o problema a um [mcve] e se ater a um problema específico conforme o [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Para entender melhor como funciona o site, seria bom uma lida no [Guia de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Seria interessante [edit] para tirar as ambiguidades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Não use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (ou "use com moderação")

Sim, eu sei que "funciona", que a solução ficou bem "fácil", com um código "simples", como mostrado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450350/112052). Não estou dizendo que ela está errada, só acho que vale a pena mencionar os problemas de usar `eval` indiscriminadamente. Concordo que realmente parece muito bom e é muito tentador não usar. Mas `eval`, [além de ser controverso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/112052), esconde vários perigos, já que ele pode executar **qualquer código arbitrário** que for passado (os exemplos abaixo foram retirados [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001)):

```
# eval executa **qualquer coisa**, sem "pensar"

# comandos arbitrários que fazem coisas que você não quer
eval("__import__('os').remove('arquivo_importante')") # apaga um arquivo que não deveria ser apagado 

# cálculo demorado (consome CPU e memória)
eval("9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9", {'__builtins__': None})
```

É claro que se você "tem certeza" que só vai receber expressões numéricas válidas e "simples", não terá problemas ao usar `eval`. Mas usá-lo indiscriminadamente, sem pensar, sem ao menos validar a string que é passada para ele, [pode causar vários problemas](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Na [resposta já *linkada* anteriormente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001) é mostrado como fazer um *parser* que só aceita expressões numéricas, além de poder limitar o valor máximo de cada operação (assim você evita casos de expressões que podem gerar números muito grandes, antes que eles estourem a memória):

```
import ast
import operator as op
import functools

def limit(max_=None):
    """Decorator que limita o valor do resultado."""
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                mag = abs(ret)
            except TypeError:
                pass # not applicable
            else:
                if mag > max_:
                    raise ValueError(f'resultado acima do valor máximo permitido: {ret}')
            return ret
        return wrapper
    return decorator

# operações suportadas
operators = {ast.Add: op.add, ast.Sub: op.sub, ast.Mult: op.mul,
             ast.Div: op.truediv, ast.Pow: op.pow, ast.BitXor: op.xor,
             ast.USub: op.neg}

# você pode sobrescrever operações, definindo valores limites para os operandos
# eu poderia fazer algo similar para todas as operações acima
def pow_limited(a, b):
    if any(abs(n) > 100 for n in [a, b]):
        raise ValueError(f'operandos da exponenciação devem ser menores que 100: {(a,b)}')
    return op.pow(a, b)
operators[ast.Pow] = pow_limited

@limit(max_=10**100) # valor máximo do resultado limitado em 10**100 (se der mais que isso, lança um ValueError)
def eval_(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Num): # <number>
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp): # <left> <operator> <right>
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left), eval_(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp): # <operator> <operand> e.g., -1
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.operand))
    else:
        raise TypeError(f'Expressão inválida: {node}')

def eval_expr(expr):
    return eval_(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)
```

Alguns exemplos de uso:

```
print(eval_expr('5 + 2 * 5')) # 15

# ou, para o seu caso específico
valores = ('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')
print(eval_expr(''.join(valores))) # 15

try:
    print(eval_expr("9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9")) # lança um ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    print(e) # operandos da exponenciação devem ser menores que 100: (9, 387420489)

try:
    print(eval_expr("10 ** 100 + 1")) # lança um ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    print(e) # resultado acima do valor máximo permitido: 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

try:
    # lança um TypeError
    print(eval_expr("__import__('os').remove('arquivo_importante')"))
except TypeError as e:
    print(e) # Expressão inválida: <_ast.Call object at 0x00F4C790>

try:
    # lança um TypeError
    print(eval_expr("a + 1"))
except TypeError as e:
    print(e) # Expressão inválida: <_ast.Name object at 0x02DAC7F0>
```

---

Infelizmente, segundo a [documentação do módulo `ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), a classe `ast.Num` usada no código acima estará *deprecated* a partir do Python 3.8 e poderá ser removida em versões futuras (testei o código no Python 3.7 e ainda funciona).

Neste caso, você ainda pode fazer seu próprio *parser*, ou instalar algum já existente. Um bom exemplo é o [`numexpr`](https://pypi.org/project/numexpr/):

```
import numexpr as ne

print(ne.evaluate('5 + 2 * 5')) # 15
print(ne.evaluate('__import__('os').remove('arquivo_importante')')) # SyntaxError
```

[Veja a documentação do `numexpr`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/) para mais detalhes.

Pode parecer exagero instalar um pacote "só" para isso, mas o simples fato de não aceitar qualquer coisa (como o `eval`) já é uma grande vantagem (apesar de ainda ter o problema de não poder limitar o valor máximo de operações intermediárias, como feito no código anterior com `pow_limited`).

---

Claro que você também pode validar a expressão, e só chamar `eval` se ela for válida. Uma forma bem "ingênua" seria verificar se todos os elementos da tupla são números ou operações matemáticas:

```
def is_valid(expr):
    def _valid(s):
        if s in ('+', '-', '*', '/', '**'): # verifica se é uma operação válida
            return True
        try: # tenta transformar em número
            int(s) # ou float(s), se quiser aceitar números com casas decimais
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    # verifica se todos os elementos são válidos (números ou operações)
    return all(_valid(s) for s in expr)

def evaluate(valores):
    if is_valid(valores):
        return eval(''.join(valores))
    raise ValueError('Não é uma expressão válida')

valores = ('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')
print(evaluate(valores)) # 15
print(evaluate(("__import__('os')", ".remove('arquivo_importante')"))) # ValueError
```

Como eu disse, esta é uma forma bem ingênua, pois ela valida apenas as partes e não toda a expressão em si. Então se a tupla só tiver operações, ou números e operações fora de ordem, etc, ela é erroneamente considerada válida. Se só tiver números, como por exemplo `('4', '2')`, o `join` os juntará e o resultado será `42`. Mas se só tiver operações (como `('*', '/')`) ou expressões incompletas/inválidas (como `('4', '*')`), ocorrerá um [`SyntaxError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError) (neste caso você poderia capturá-lo com um bloco `try`/`except`, para saber se deu erro, por exemplo).

Apesar de ser um solução simplista, já elimina muitos casos de códigos arbitrários e maliciosos. E ainda seria possível limitar os valores dos operandos dentro da função `_valid`, por exemplo.

Obviamente que um *parser* mais completo que aceite somente expressões aritméticas [seria um pouco mais complexo que isso](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part7/), mas talvez seja a solução mais adequada.

E como apontado pelo [@jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/500/jsbueno) nos comentários, talvez você nem precise de `join` para gerar a string. Se a tupla já está devidamente *tokenizada* (ou seja, cada elemento dela já é uma parte da expressão), bastaria transformá-la em uma árvore e calcular o resultado (como exemplo, foi mencionado [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tCNu4CnjVc)).

Uma versão **bem simplista** (e muito menos completa do que os links acima mencionados) seria:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

operators = { '+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv }

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        if value in operators:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = float(value)
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def is_op(self):
        return self.value in operators

    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.right is None and self.left is None

    def calc(self):
        if self is None:
            return 0
        if self.is_leaf():
            return self.value
        return operators[self.value](self.left.calc(), self.right.calc())

    def right_most(self):
        r, parent = self, None
        while r.right is not None:
            parent, r = r, r.right
        return r, parent

valores = ('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')

def create_tree(valores):
    root = Node(valores[0])
    if root.is_op():
        raise ValueError('expressão inválida')

    for v in valores[1:]:
        node = Node(v)
        if node.is_op() and not root.is_op():
            node.left = root
            root = node
        elif root.is_op() and not node.is_op():
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            elif root.right is None:
                root.right = node
            else:
                root.right_most()[0].right = node
        elif root.is_op() and node.is_op():
            if node.value in ('*', '/'):
                r, parent = root.right_most()
                node.left = r
                parent.right = node
            else:
                node.left = root
                root = node

    return root

root = create_tree(valores)
print(root.calc()) # 15.0
```

Pode parecer trabalho demais quando "já existe algo pronto", mas pelo menos só aceitará expressões válidas (uma expressão inválida dará erro ou na hora de construir a árvore, ou ao calcular o valor - como eu disse, é bem simplista, só para ter uma ideia de como ficaria, então não deixe de seguir os links indicados para um versão mais completa). Se não quiser construir por si só, pode usar o `numexpr` por exemplo.

Este código é bem simplista porque só aceita as 4 operações básicas, não considera parênteses, etc (e não fiz testes extensivos com expressões muito complexas, pode ser que precise de alguns ajustes ainda). Basicamente ela pega cada elemento da tupla e vai montando uma árvore. No caso de `('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')`, ficaria assim:

```
    +
   / \
  5   *
     / \
    2   5
```

As operações com maior precedência vão sendo jogadas para baixo. E para calculá-la, ele vai resolvendo de baixo para cima (primeiro faz a multiplicação de 2 com 5, e depois faz a soma de 5 com o resultado da multiplicação).

O resultado é `15.0` porque transformei os números em [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float). Mas se quiser aceitar apenas números inteiros, use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) no lugar.

---

Por fim, sobre o `eval`, não deixe de ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326937/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/112052). Não que seja totalmente errado usá-lo, mas é importante entender os problemas que ele pode causar, para que você tome os devidos cuidados.

Comment: Eu sei que chamar a outra resp de "errada" seria um pouco de exagero talvez, mas acho um péssimo exemplo de solução para um site que se propõe como referência. E pra piorar a situação, claramente se a resposta serviu, era um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/70) do autor da pergunta, pois ele parte de um código razoavelmente pronto e troca por uma solução reprovável. No meu ver a única resposta possível para a pergunta seria pegar o que já foi usado no código e completar corrigindo (mas aí já vira "faz pra mim", pois a pergunta não especifica o problema central com clareza).

Comment: pra ser "certo" aí  o bom é não usar eval. A tupla já está "tokenizada" - o que é metade do problema resolvido para criar uma árvore e ter uma soluçao dinâmica.  Comentei na outra resposta com o link pra um vídeo bem maneiro.

Comment: @jsbueno Ah sim, é que me preocupei tanto em alertar para os problemas do `eval` que esqueci de mencionar isso. De fato, montar uma árvore a partir da tupla é bem melhor do que criar uma string só pra fazer o parsing de novo. Se der tempo eu faço isso (se bem que [um dos links](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part7/) no final da resposta já tem um parser bem completinho implementado), mas meu objetivo foi mais alertar para o uso do `eval` mesmo. Achei meio "inconsequente" (irresponsável até) sugerir o seu uso sem ao menos avisar dos problemas que ele tem...

Comment: @jsbueno Sobre o `numexpr`, eu fiz umas pesquisas rápidas e acabei achando ele uma boa opção para avaliar expressões aritméticas. Mas vc sabe se existem outras alternativas tão boas quanto ou melhores?

Comment: "eval" nem tem tantos problemas assim - não é religião - se você souber o que está colocando pra ele, é tão perigoso quanto qualquer query em qualquer banco de dados (qualquer query, afinal, é uam string no código da linguagem de origem, que "roda" (ou seja, a mesma coisa que um eval) dentro do banco de dados.

Comment: @jsbueno Sim, talvez eu tenha exagerado no "tom alarmista". Mas assim como uma resposta que sugere usar um código suscetível a SQL injection não é uma resposta boa, entendo o mesmo de uma resposta que sugere usar `eval` sem ao menos mencionar que ela pode dar problema se não tomar cuidado. De qualquer forma, obrigado pelos comentários sempre pertinentes :-)

Comment: @jsbueno Coloquei uma versão **bem** simplificada da árvore, só para mostrar a ideia geral, pois nos links indicados já tem versões mais completas (e também porque fiquei com preguiça de elaborar mais...) De qualquer forma, aí está :-)

Answer (score 4):

Para transformar uma lista em string no Python, podemos utilizar o método `join` da *str*:

```
valores = ('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')
soma = ' '.join(valores)
print(soma)
```

Com isso, os valores de sua tupla vão formar uma string, cada valor separado por um espaço: `"5 + 2 * 5"`

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/TragicRotatingDecagon

---

Caso você queira ter o valor dessa expressão formada, você pode utilizar a função `eval`:

```
valores = ('5', '+', '2', '*', '5')
soma = eval(''.join(valores))
print(soma)
```

*Obs.: Aqui não coloquei o espaço, como um outro exemplo.*

O resultado aqui será `15`, pois a expressão será avaliada, multiplicando e somando os valores.

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/KhakiSpiffyCron

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Se já você já tem os tokens separados - juntar tudo numa string e fazer eval, vi funcionar, mais, vamos cmbinar que é "pobrinho" não é?  Até acho que é legal como solução rápida - mas o legal a partir da tupla. é criar uma árvore com as operações e os operandos nas folhas -  e resolver o problema assim. Outro dia vi um vídeo bem didático  de um professor vovozão fazendo isso -deixa eu ver se acho.

Comment: Achei - sao 22 minutos só - dá um bicada - é muito mais simples do que a gente pensa a principio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tCNu4CnjVc