# Como ser mais cauteloso ao utilizar a função eval?

Tags: python-3.x, eval

Eu possuo uma função que obtém uma conta e a calcula utilizando a função `eval`. A minha dúvida é, como posso ser mais cauteloso ao utilizar esta função ?

```
def calcula(string):
     if type(eval(string)) in [float, int]:
         resultado = eval(string)
         return resultado

conta = str(input('Digite a conta'))
# Ex: '5**2 + 0.5'          
calcula(conta)
```

Criei uma validação para a string no `if`. Isso é o suficiente para evitar que a entrada do usuário afete o programa ?

Comment: Não é fácil dar uma resposta para isso. Acho que ela seria bem longa. Em essência só estará seguro sanilizando o conteúdo digitado, o que é um processo bem complicado. Talvez tenha uma biblioteca que já faça isso. Se não fizer isso não está sendo cauteloso e todo tipo de problema de segurança pode ocorrer. Claro que em um exercício isso não é relevante, mas estará exercitando o jeito errado de fazer isso e aprenderá que o `eval()` é mocinho. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101. O ideal é aprender fazer do jeito certo ou não fazer o errado.

Comment: Geralmente o problema do eval é quem usa. Se a função existe, tem uma razão, mas infelizmente não é usado certo praticamente nunca. O pessoal que defende muito eval sem critérios geralmente tem preguiça de programar, prefere "amontoar" código. Esse caso seu claramente não é caso de eval, até porque fazer um "conserto" pra deixar o eval seguro é mais crítico do que fazer o código certo sem eval (e nesse caso, fazer certo, é mais inteligente em todos os sentidos). Vide comentário na atual resposta aceita.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450398/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo eu sabia que tinha a sua, não lembra que era tão recente e da mesma pessoa. È o mesmo caso de ter a esmagadora maioria de perguntas com *query* sofrendo de SQL Injection. As pessoas querem fazer o errado de qualquer jeito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como o Maniero falou nos comentários da questão, uma resposta para como ser cauteloso ao utilizar a função `eval` seria muito longa.

Mas agora focando na sua tarefa e assumindo que você não está sendo tão exigente com a segurança do seu código, a sua validação não é nem um pouco segura.

Isso porque já na validação, você executa na função `eval` a entrada do usuário para obter o tipo do retorno da função. No final das contas, o seu programa já terá executado a entrada validando ou não o que o usuário inseriu.

Uma solução bastante simples para seu problema, é verificar cada caractere da string para saber se há algum caractere indesejado que possa significar uma entrada que afete o seu programa.

```
def calculate(expression):
    allowed_chars = "*-+/()1234567890 "

    for char in expression:
        if not char in allowed_chars:
            return "O caractere %s não é válido." % char

    return eval(expression)
```

Comment: Ficou boa e simples a solução paro que foi perguntado, mas ainda assim considero uma gambiarra danada (não é culpa sua, é o que foi perguntado). Não é uma solução escalável, inclusive, pois se o autor precisar amanha ou depois aceitar algumas funções (raiz quadrada, arredondamento, etc) , já vai ter que permitir uma série de caracteres a mais, e assim vai "cavando a cova" para deixar passar algo danoso. Só deixei o comentário pra quem vier futuramente pesquisar a mesma coisa já estar "avisado".

Answer (score -4):

Não, o if não é suficiente, experimenta com o try except

```
def calcula(string):
       try:
           resultado = eval(string)
           return resultado
       except Exception:
           print("Não é uma operação válida")
```