# Torre de Hanoi recursivo com contador de jogadas

Tags: python, recursão

Eu escrevi este codigo recursivo da torre de hanoi e estava a tentar implementar uma secção  que me dissesse o número mínimo de jogadas necessárias e em que jogada estavamos ( acrescentar uma jogada sempre que esta mudasse).

Por exemplo se houvessem 3 discos:

```
Primeira jogada: Tower 1 --> Tower 2
etc...
Número minimo de jogadas: 7
```

Como é que poderia implementar isto? Recursivamente? Com iteração e ciclos? Já tentei recursivamente mas perdi-me no meu raciocínio e não consegui resolver o problema sem reformular tudo.

```
def hanoi():

    def mova(n, origem, destino, aux):
        
        def mova_disco(de, para):
            print("Tower", de, "-->", "Tower", para, "\n\n")


        if n == 1:
            mova_disco(origem, destino)

        else:
            mova(n - 1, origem, aux, destino)
            mova_disco(origem, destino)
            mova(n - 1, aux, destino, origem)

    n = eval(input("Quantos discos deseja considerar? \n -->"))
    print("Solução do puzzle: \n")
    mova(n, "1", "3", "2")

#Running the code

hanoi()
```

Comment: Em português, por favor, já que estamos no [pt.so]

Comment: E ao traduzir, poderia explicar o motivo de ter utilizado o `eval` na entrada do usuário?

Comment: @Woss já traduzi. Usei o evalei como usaria o "int(input)", só por habito e porque eles usam no livro que estou a ler. Mas funcionam de modo parecido penso eu.

Comment: `eval` não é a mesma coisa que `int`. A diferença é que `int` converte para número e dá erro se tiver qualquer coisa que não for um número, enquanto `eval` aceita qualquer comando válido, podendo inclusive ser perigoso, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450398/112052) - se o livro diz pra usar `eval` e não alerta para esses problemas, eu já olharia com desconfiança...

Comment: Ok, entendi. Obrigado. Vou ter isso em conta nas próximas vezes antes de usar eval :)
Em relação ao problema do algoritmo tem ideia de como é que poderia resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer com que as funções recebam o número da jogada atual, e retornem esse número atualizado.

E como o total de jogadas para N discos sempre é 2<sup>N</sup> - 1, você pode imprimir esse valor diretamente:

```
def hanoi():
    def mova(n, origem, destino, aux, jogada):
        def mova_disco(de, para, jogada):
            print(f"Jogada {jogada:>3}: Tower {de} --> Tower {para}")
            return jogada + 1 # atualiza para a próxima jogada

        if n == 1:
            jogada = mova_disco(origem, destino, jogada)
        else:
            jogada = mova(n - 1, origem, aux, destino, jogada)
            jogada = mova_disco(origem, destino, jogada)
            jogada = mova(n - 1, aux, destino, origem, jogada)

        return jogada

    n = int(input("Quantos discos deseja considerar? \n -->"))
    print(f"Solução do puzzle ({2 ** n - 1} jogadas): \n")
    mova(n, "1", "3", "2", 1)

hanoi()
```

Ou seja, quando eu mover o disco, eu imprimo a jogada atual e retorno a jogada seguinte. E a cada movimento eu pego esse retorno e passo para o movimento seguinte.

Repare também que usei [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (disponíveis a partir do Python 3.6) para imprimir as mensagens. No caso da jogada, também usei as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) (no caso, `>3` para alinhar os números à direita, ocupando 3 posições).

E troquei [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) por [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), já que `int` converte o que for digitado para número (e dá erro se não for um número), enquanto `eval` executa qualquer coisa que for digitada, inclusive comandos potencialmente perigosos ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450398/112052) para mais detalhes).

---

Outra solução (pior, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/112052) para mais detalhes) é ter uma variável global como contador de jogadas:

```
jogada = 1 # variável global
def hanoi():
    def mova(n, origem, destino, aux):
        def mova_disco(de, para):
            global jogada # referenciar a variável global
            print(f"Jogada {jogada:>3}: Tower {de} --> Tower {para}")
            jogada += 1 # atualizar o contador

        if n == 1:
            mova_disco(origem, destino)
        else:
            mova(n - 1, origem, aux, destino)
            mova_disco(origem, destino)
            mova(n - 1, aux, destino, origem)

    n = int(input("Quantos discos deseja considerar? \n -->"))
    print(f"Solução do puzzle ({2 ** n - 1} jogadas): \n")
    mova(n, "1", "3", "2")

hanoi()
```