# formatar uma lista em python

Tags: python

não estou a conseguir formatar a linha  `print('{0:>20}'.format('Alunos:'),melhores)` em que tenho de mostrar os melhores alunos como aparece na imagem, conseguem ajudar-me?[image: exemplo de resposta]

```
# coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import math
nAlunos=0
while True:
    while True:
        nAlunos=eval(input('Indique o número de alunos:'))
        if 1<=nAlunos<=100:
            break
        else:
            print('O número de alunos tem de ser entre 1 e 100');print()
    ListaNomes=[0 for i in range(0,nAlunos)]
    ListaNotas=[0 for i in range(0,nAlunos)]
    reprovados = suficiente = bom = muitobom = 0
    for i in range(0,nAlunos):
        ListaNomes[i]=input('Nome:')
        while True:
            ListaNotas[i]=eval(input('Nota:'))
            if 0<=ListaNotas[i]<=20:
                if 0<=ListaNotas[i]<10:
                    reprovados=reprovados+1
                elif 10<=ListaNotas[i]<14:
                    suficiente=suficiente+1
                elif 14<=ListaNotas[i]<17:
                    bom=bom+1
                elif 17<=ListaNotas[i]<20:
                    muitobom=muitobom+1
                break
            else:
                print('A nota tem de estar entre 0 e 20');print() 
    PercentagemReprovados=(reprovados*100)/len(ListaNotas)
    PercentagemSuficiente=(suficiente*100)/len(ListaNotas)
    PercentagemBom=(bom*100)/len(ListaNotas)
    PercentagemMuitobom=(muitobom*100)/len(ListaNotas)
    print();print('{0:>20}{1:>15}'.format('NOME','NOTA'));print()
    for i in range(0,nAlunos):
        print('{0:>20}{1:>15.1f}'.format(ListaNomes[i],ListaNotas[i]))
    print();print()
    print('{0:>20}{1:>15}{2:1}'.format('Reprovados:',round(PercentagemReprovados),'%'))
    print();print('{0:>20}'.format('Aprovados:'))
    print('{0:>19}{1:>16}{2:1}'.format('suficiente',round(PercentagemSuficiente),'%'))
    print('{0:>19}{1:>16}{2:1}'.format('bom',round(PercentagemBom),'%'))
    print('{0:>19}{1:>16}{2:1}'.format('muito bom',round(PercentagemMuitobom),'%'));print()
    print('{0:>20}{1:>16.1f}'.format('Melhor nota:',max(ListaNotas)))
    melhor_nota=max(ListaNotas)
    melhores=[ListaNomes[i] for i in range(len(ListaNotas)) if ListaNotas[i] == melhor_nota]
    print('{0:>20}'.format('Alunos:'),melhores)
    print()
    resp=input('Repetir?(S/N)').upper()
    while (len(resp)!=1)or(resp not in 'SN'):
        print('Valor inválido!')
        resp = input('Repetir?(S/N)').upper()
    if resp=='N':
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`melhores` é uma lista que pode ter vários alunos, então como deveria estar formatado? Um por linha, todos na mesma linha?

Todos na mesma linha acho que não é uma boa opção, pois se tiver vários, vai ultrapassar o tamanho da coluna facilmente. Então acho melhor colocar um por linha:

```
for aluno in melhores:
    print('{0:>20}{1:>16}'.format('Aluno:', aluno))
```

Exemplo de saída com mais de um aluno:

```
        Melhor nota:            10.0
              Aluno:          fulano
              Aluno:        beltrano
```

Se estiver usando Python >= 3.6 também pode usar [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) no lugar de `format`:

```
for aluno in melhores:
    print(f'{"Aluno:":>20}{aluno:>16}')
```

---

Aproveitando, não use `eval` para converter o que foi digitado para número, pois [além de ser controverso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/112052), ele [esconde algumas armadilhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450398/112052). Prefira usar [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
nAlunos = int(input('Indique o número de alunos:'))
```

Comment: Ainda não percebi muito bem como usar o f-string no lugar de format, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela dica